# Comparing multiple variables and assigning new values respectively

Tags: javascript

I know there is a more elegant way to write this.  The logic is solid and doing what I want it to, but I feel like when written like this, it is awfully cumbersome to have these many `if` statements essentially doing the same thing.

```
if (forward) {
    if (counter == listEnd) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
    }

    if (nextCounter == listEnd) {
        nextCounter = 0;
    }
    else {
        nextCounter++;
    }

    if (prevCounter == listEnd) {
        prevCounter = 0;
    }
    else {
        prevCounter++;
    }
} // end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a function:

```
var boundedIncrement = function(current, maximum) {
    return current === maximum ? 0 : current + 1;
};
```

Then use it:

```
if (forward) {
    counter = boundedIncrement(counter, listEnd);
    nextCounter = boundedIncrement(nextCounter, listEnd);
    prevCounter = boundedIncrement(prevCounter, listEnd);
}
```

No more logic duplication.

You could also close over listEnd if you wanted to have a single argumented function:

```
if (forward) {
    var boundedIncrement = function(current) {
         return current === listEnd ? 0 : current + 1;
    };
    counter = boundedIncrement(counter);
    nextCounter = boundedIncrement(nextCounter);
    prevCounter = boundedIncrement(prevCounter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a function?

```
function incr(counter){
    if (counter == listEnd) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return counter + 1;
    }
}
if (forward){
    counter = incr(counter);
    nextCounter = incr(nextCounter);
    prevCounter = incr(prevCounter);
}
```

Then you can pass any value to it if `listEnd` is always the same value for each. If not, then just add `listEnd` as a second parameter.